# PHP - selecting input type using REGEX

Tags: php, html, regex

I apologyze for the title , i didn't know how to express it properly 
But here is the issue :

```
preg_match_all("/  (<input[^>]+>)  |  <select[^>]+>(.+?)<\/select  |  <textarea[^>]+>([^<]+)  /xims", $form, $matches);
```

in the form i'm looking at, there is a File upload input

```
<input type="file" name="upload">
```

but when i do the

```
print_r($matches);
```

I get the "text" fields but there's no "file" field fetched ..

I want to include the "file" input type in $matches[] as well.

i'm very weak in regex, and i googled alot but found nothing precise..
I'll appreciate your answer, Thanks.

Comment: check and correct your syntax `int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/(?:<(select|textarea)[^>]*>[^<]+<\/\1>)|(<input[^>]*type=\"([a-z]+)\"[^>]*\/?>)/ximsg
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDYM7u/1/)

Sample Source: ([Run here](http://ideone.com/q0uRWm))

```
$re = '/(?:<(select|textarea)[^>]*>[^<]+<\/\1>)|(<input[^>]*type=\"([a-z]+)\"[^>]*\/?>)/xims';
$str = '<input type="file" name="upload">
<input type="text" name="upload1">
<select > bla bla bla </select>
<textarea>abc</textarea>
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```